# How to read CSS Content value with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, attributes

Ok,this is bothering me, i beleive it is simple but I am having trouble.

I have a css definition:

```
.isMobile{content:'No'}
```

And I have HTML:

```
<ins class="isMobile"></ins>
```

My question is how I read the content value into javascript using jQuery.
I have tried, google and tried again and the closest I can get is

```
$("ins.cdo").css( "content" );
```

which returns "" not undefined. The desired result is either Yes or No.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Your JQuery is not targeting your HTML maybe?, otherwise it should work. Try removing the '.cdo' part

Comment: `.isMobile{content:No}` tried this?

Comment: Shouldn’t `$('.isMobile').css('content')` be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS `content` property is used with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements and shouldn't be used in the way you are intending.

Instead, this sounds like a good use case for data attributes. Here is how you would achieve your intended results with them:

First add the `data-content` attribute to your `ins` element, assigning it the value `"No"`.

```
<ins class="isMobile" data-content="No"></ins>
```

Then with jQuery, you can get the value of the data attribute like this

```
$(".isMobile").data("content");
```

You can also change the value of the attribute like this

```
$(".isMovile").data("content", "Yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

This can fetch the value of the CSS property.

```
$("ins.isMobile").css( "content" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are unable to get the content property is because your selector is wrong try this

```
$("ins.isMobile").css("content");
```